# How to calculate RSI in python 3x

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I wrote this code for calculating the RSI of past 14 days price of BTC but I'm not sure is this is correct below is my code if any one can help

```
higher       = []
lower        = []
past14Days   = [6971.73, 6937.08, 8218.05, 9251.27, 8870.82, 9114.72, 10226.86, 10107.26, 11233.95, 11767.74, 11459.71, 11104.2, 11175.87, 11429.02]

x = 0
for i in past14Days:
    if len(past14Days)-1 >= x+1:

        if past14Days[x+1] > past14Days[x]:
            high = past14Days[x+1] - past14Days[x]
            higher.append(high)

        elif past14Days[x+1] < past14Days[x]:
            low = past14Days[x] - past14Days[x+1]
            lower.append(low)
    x+=1

upwordAvg   = sum(higher) / len(higher) 
downwordAvg = sum(lower) / len(lower)
print(upwordAvg)
print(downwordAvg)
RS          = upwordAvg / downwordAvg
RSI         = 100 - (100/(1+RS))

print(RSI)
```

Comment: What's the expected output? and are you getting any errors?

Comment: This is  a question for CodeReview, and btw there already was one around RSI: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51406/calculating-relative-strength-index-over-a-period

Comment: I get 74.68300004463393 this value but I'm not sure this is correct or not the problem is that I dont know that my calculation is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the issue here is that the output of code cannot be checked against something. In order to check the output, I would suggest to take a pencil and a paper (or Excel) and arrive to a figure manually. Then, compare it with what your python code delivers. Only then you know the python code delivers what you meant for. If you are not sure about the way how to compute RSI, take a look at [this link](https://nullbeans.com/how-to-calculate-the-relative-strength-index-rsi/) (they claim they compute RSI according to TradingView, one of reputable websites in trading). However, no python therein (but java). Hope it will help you clarify your requirements you have from your python code.